# Premiere Pro CS6 (Windows) Playback doesn't work

Tags: playback

I have Premiere Pro CS6 installed and I have two videos in my timeline and when I press the "play" button to playback it doesn't do anything it just does literally nothing. Also when I scrub through my project there is no audio.

I have just updated to Windows 10 and I'm now having this issue I have reset my preferences and updated to Premiere Pro Update 6.0.5 (Latest) still nothing is working!

Pleaseee help.. I need to edit this backlog of videos I have.

System Specs:
Intel Core i7-4770
RAM: DDR3 12GB 1600MHz
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 750Ti 2GB
HDD: 1TB
SSD: 240GB

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because of being off topic. Such questions must be asked in Super User QA.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens after upgrading to windows 10 try downgrading your GTX card to previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading [Nvidia GeForce Experience](http://www.nvidia.it/object/geforce-experience-it.html) and using it to update the drivers with ones that work with windows 10 will fix the problem. I've had this problem myself bit with adobe CC

Answer (score 0):

Edit > Preferences > Audio Hardware

Set Device Class to MME or AISO and set default output to Speakers/Headphone

If you set AISO tick the Attempt to force hardware to document sample rate